# facing issue to add Data from dictionary into datafram

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, openweathermap

Facing trouble creating a function to store the response in columns,
Like passing the city name and as the response getting details of max_temp, min_temp, Pressure. which I want to store that in the new column.

```
import pyowm
from pyowm.utils import config
from pyowm.utils import timestamps

api_key = {key from openweather(free)}
mgr = owm.weather_manager()
data =[]
def get_weather(city):
    observation = mgr.weather_at_place(city)
    l = observation.weather
    Wind_Speed = l.wind()['speed']
    Temp = l.temperature('celsius')['temp']
    Max_temp = l.temperature('celsius')['temp_max']
    Min_temp = l.temperature('celsius')['temp_min']
    #Heat_index = l.heat_index
    Humidity = l.humidity
    Pressure = l.pressure['press']
    weather = {"City": city,"Wind_Speed" : Wind_Speed, "Temp": 
    Temp,"Max_temp":Max_temp, "Min_temp":Min_temp, "Humidity":Humidity,
                  "Pressure":Pressure}
    
    return weather

for city in df2['City']:
    get_weather(city)
    df = df.append(data, True)
```

Want to add each weather details as column based on city name

Want to create one function which stores all the details in columns,
don't want to create separate functions.

Data Frame is like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a dictionary from your fucntion.

```
def get_weather(city):
    observation = mgr.weather_at_place(city)
    l = observation.weather
    Wind_Speed = l.wind()['speed']
    Temp = l.temperature('celsius')['temp']
    Max_temp = l.temperature('celsius')['temp_max']
    resp=dict()
    resp['Wind_Speed ']=Wind_Speed 
    resp['Temp']=Temp 
    resp['Max_temp']=Max_temp  
    return resp

df["Wind_speed"] = df["city"].apply(lambda x: get_weather(x)['Wind_Speed'])
df["Temp"] = df["city"].apply(lambda x: get_weather(x)['Temp'])
df["Max_temp"] = df["city"].apply(lambda x: get_weather(x)['Max_temp'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay, but question that how to create a single function to get the all details, don't want to create separate functions like above. (question updated)

Comment: df[['Wind_speed',' max_temp','Pressure',' min_temp' ] ]= df["city"].apply(lambda x: get_weather(x)) .  Do you want something like this?

Comment: In this case for each column function will call, so it will take lots of time.
In single call getting all the details so want to use the way where I can store the data in df for the entire row.

Comment: Not necessary to create function is there any way where we can use only for look to get and store data in DF.

Comment: In that case call the function ones using city to get dict of response, make a dataFrame with single row , add the values from dict to the row, append it to parent dataFrame.  I believe there is no one line code for this purpose.